# java swing to count all controls

Tags: java, swingworker

How to count number of controls like JTextField, J Label and so on so..in java swing form designing,for example if we use only one textbox and one text field  means i need the output as follows count value is  2.how to do this?

Comment: Would you need to count JPanels as well? If they are used as nested containers.

Answer (score 2):

The container for the controls contains a list of controls, see `Container.getComponents()`.  Come to think, it also has a method for the count of the controls, if that's all you want, `Container.getComponentCount().`

If you want this for all the controls contained within containers contained (ultimately) in a frame, you will need to look at each one recursively; start with the frame, and for each component that is a container, get the controls/count in that container, etc.  Keep in mind that panels can have panels.

rc

Answer (score 0):

As they should all be inside your `Container` object you can use the `getComponentCount()` method to return you an `int` of the number of components.

```
Container c;
int count;
count = c.getComponentCount();
```

Answer (score 0):

With SwingX, you have in class **org.jdesktop.swingx.util.WindowUtils** `public static List<Component> getAllComponents(Container c)`. With that you have all components and subcomponents in container.