# Count all components(controls) in java swing form

Tags: java, swing, jcomponent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java swing to count all controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556982/java-swing-to-count-all-controls)

How to count the number of components which are used in a particular form in a Java swing GUI? 
If I'm using 3 `JTextField`s and 3 `JLabels`s the number of controls are used in that form should be 6. How can I count them?

Answer (score 3):

Use `public int getComponentCount()` method of the form assuming it extends JComponent (and in turn Container). Iterate all sub components asking each of them their count recoursively.